# Is it possible to turn off syntax highlighting in Asciidoctor?

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor, asciidoctor-pdf

I've used [Asciidoctor](http://asciidoctor.org/) to create my [JHipster Mini-Book](https://www.infoq.com/minibooks/jhipster-4-mini-book). It looks great in PDF, MOBI, EPUB, and HTML. I've also created a (PDF) version that's printable. The printable version goes though Lulu, and gets printed in black and white.

The printable PDF has its code listings in color, which causes the code listings to be hard to read when printed, especially if they're light gray (e.g., comments). Is there a way to turn off syntax-highlighting in Asciidoctor?

Comment: Did you look at http://gist.asciidoctor.org/?github-asciidoctor%2Fasciidoctor-pdf%2F%2Fdocs%2Ftheming-guide.adoc ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer with the help of @mojavelinux (Dan Allen) on Twitter. The key is not to pass in the `source-highlighter` argument.

Here's my `generate-pdf.sh` script after making this change.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Usage: `./generate-pdf.sh` to generate a printable 6x9" PDF with no syntax highlighting
#        `./generate-pdf.sh screen` to generate a downloadable 8.5x11" PDF

source $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm

rvm use 2.3.1 --quiet
if [ ! -d .bundle/gems ]; then
  rm -f Gemfile.lock
  bundle config --local github.https true
  bundle --path=.bundle/gems --binstubs=.bundle/.bin
fi

if [ -f "$rvm_path/scripts/rvm" ] && [ -f ".ruby-version" ] && [ -f ".ruby-gemset" ]; then
  source "$rvm_path/scripts/rvm"
  rvm use `cat .ruby-version`@`cat .ruby-gemset`
fi

ASCIIDOCTOR_PDF="./.bundle/.bin/asciidoctor-pdf"
OPTIMIZE_PDF="`bundle exec gem contents --show-install-dir asciidoctor-pdf`/bin/optimize-pdf"

ROOT_DIR=$(realpath $(dirname $0))
MEDIA=prepress
HIGHLIGHTING=""
if [ ! -z "$1" ]; then
  MEDIA=$1
  HIGHLIGHTING="-a source-highlighter=coderay"
fi
BASE_DIR="$ROOT_DIR/src/docs/asciidoc"
OUT_DIR="$ROOT_DIR/build/asciidoc/pdf-$MEDIA"

$ASCIIDOCTOR_PDF --trace -B "$BASE_DIR" \
  -D "$OUT_DIR" \
  -S unsafe \
  -r "$ROOT_DIR/src/main/ruby/asciidoctor-pdf-extensions.rb" \
  -a media=$MEDIA \
  -a pdfmarks \
  -a pdf-style=infoq-$MEDIA \
  -a pdf-stylesdir="$BASE_DIR/styles/pdf" \
  -a pdf-fontsdir="$BASE_DIR/styles/pdf/fonts" \
  -a sourcedir=../../../main/webapp \
  $HIGHLIGHTING \
  -a imagesdir=images \
  -a toc \
  -a icons=font \
  -a idprefix \
  -a idseparator=- \
  -a projectdir=../../.. \
  -a rootdir=../../.. \
  -a project-name=jhipster-book \
  -a project-version=2.0.0-SNAPSHOT \
  -a attribute-missing=warn \
  "$BASE_DIR/index.adoc"

$OPTIMIZE_PDF "$OUT_DIR/index.pdf"
mv -f "$OUT_DIR/index-optimized.pdf" "$OUT_DIR/index.pdf"
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy way would be to not to say which language the code has.  Just replace

```
[source,ruby]
----
require 'sinatra'
----
```

with

```
[source]
----
require 'sinatra'
----
```

Comment: Right, but that would turn off all the syntax highlight in the other artifacts (downloadable PDF, MOBI, and EPUB). The syntax highlighting looks great in those files.

Answer (score 0):

Set attribute `source-highlighter` to `html-pipeline`, e.g. on CLI when calling asciidoctor:

```
asciidoctor -a source-highlighter=html-pipeline FILE
```